# How to load a resource file from url?

Tags: android, http, android-resources, android-developer-api

- I have an application that loads a configuration.xml file from res/raw file using this line :

  Example:

  ```
      Resources resources = context.getResources();
      InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(ResourceIds.raw.configuration);
  ```
- I want to put the configuration.xml file into a server folder (http url) and then i can load it like this  :

  Example:

  ```
      Resources resources = context.getResources();
      InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(http://example.com/folder/configuration.xml);
  ```

Can you help me with this please?!

Comment: That will not go. Any more such ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot load a resource from a URL. Use OkHttp or some other HTTP client to load the content identified by that URL.

Comment: can you provide me a simple example ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm understanding you, you need an input stream that reads your XML from a web server. That would look like this:

```
InputStream is = new URL("http://example.com/folder/configuration.xml").openConnection().getInputStream();
```

However there's much more to this, you can't do this on the main thread (see NetworkOnMainThreadException) and you have to be prepared that there is no internet connection or that it downloads slowly. So I don't know what you use this configuration for but for example you may have to have defaults and put a "please wait" message on the screen.

Comment: Hello, thnx for your reply. I m actually working on home screen customization for Android TV. When i put statically configuration.xml file under res/raw folder, i am able to do the modifications i want but it took too much time to compile the environment. So i decided to put this config file under a server so i can modify directly on it , and then the customization.apk reads this xml file from it and do the modifications i want

Comment: Well, I've never done that, but then I suppose you'll be fine with the simple code above. Just remember, you still nead to do it on a separate thread maybe with `new Thread(new Runnable { ... }).start()`

Comment: It will always fail on the main thread. Android doesn't let you do any networking stuff on the main thread because it may block the user interface and "it leads to bad user experience" or whatever.

Comment: Thnx a lot dude , your suggestion has solved my problem :D :D